# How can I make it so the map displays only 4 items and then it starts a second row

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I'm mapping some items from my mongodb cluster using tailwind, and I want just 4  items in one row.

Can't really figure out how to make it so it starts a new row by itself. Now it just mushes them together in one row.

```
<div className="flex justify-center gap-12 max-h-full max-w-full ">
      {products?.length > 0 &&
        products.map((product) => (
          <div className="w-96 p-4 border border-stone-800 items-center justify-center text-center rounded-md">
            <div className="flex justify-center">
              <img
                src={product.images[0]}
                alt={product.title}
                className="mapped-img"
              />
            </div>
            <p>{product.title}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: "and I want just 4 or 5 items in one row" - could you please define which of these you'd like please, 4 or 5? "And on small [devices] to display just 1" - could you define what viewport media query you'd consider a small device please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `grid` instead of `flex`.

1. In the parent element, replace `flex` with `grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-4` and play with the breakpoint values.
2. Remove the `w-96` on the child element, the width should be based on screen width, hardcoded width will break the layout.

Created a [tailwind playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/ZtkBWQE1SN) FYR.